# Close websocket connection in redux-observable

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm currently using `redux-observable` to handle a websocket connection but can't figure out what's the best way to handle the `close` event.

```
const webSocket$ = Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://localhost:8080'
});

export const fetchMessagesEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH.MESSAGES)
    .switchMap((action) =>
      webSocket$
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err);return true; }) <-- I can see the close event here
        .map((msg) => addMessage(msg)));
```

Should I be handling it in `catch` (sending a new action from there and then using `takeUntil` in the same epic?

Comment: You want to handle close how? Only on error (like with `catch`) or in general? The `Observable.webSocket` config has also `closingObserver` option.

Comment: Yup, but `closingObserver` would still require me to send an action from my side. What I'm looking for is to handle the `CloseEvent` sent from the server e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

Comment: Also the `CloseEvent` does show up in the websocket stream as well, but then it's also recognized as an error.

Comment: So you want the `CloseEvent` not to be an error and rather just a normal `next` notification?

Comment: That's what I'm assuming yes. From the docs, `CloseEvent` with code `1000` is a normal closure.

Comment: You can use `catch((err) => { /* whatever logic you want */ return Obsrvable.of(err)  })` to turn it into `next`

Comment: Yup that's what I do right now, but didn't seem like the best way. Thanks for looking into it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Observable.webSocket` (aka WebSocketSubject) from rxjs only sends the close event down the error path if the [CloseEvent's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent) `wasClean` value is false.

[rxjs source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L224-L235)

```
socket.onclose = (e: CloseEvent) => {
  this._resetState();
  const closeObserver = this.closeObserver;
  if (closeObserver) {
    closeObserver.next(e);
  }

  //  v------------------------ Right here
  if (e.wasClean) {
    observer.complete();
  } else {
    observer.error(e);
  }
};
```

So that means that in your case the connection is not closing correctly. There is sometimes a `reason` field on the CloseEvent that may or may not give you insight, or the Chrome Dev Tools Network and Console tabs might have more too.

When a socket is closed cleanly by the remote server, then the correct way to do something special is by passing in a `closeObserver`. Either a `{ next: func }` observer directly, or more likely a Subject (which is both an Observable and an an Observer)

```
// a stream of CloseEvents
const webSocketClose$ = new Subject();
const webSocket$ = Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://localhost:8080',
  closeObserver: webSocketClose$
});

export const fetchMessagesEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH.MESSAGES)
    .switchMap((action) => {
      const message$ = webSocket$
        .map((msg) => addMessage(msg))
        .catch((e) => Observable.of({
          type: 'SOCKET_ERROR',
          error: e
        }));

      const close$ = webSocketClose$
        .take(1) // you probably only want one
        .map((event) => ({
          type: 'SOCKET_CLOSE_EVENT',
          wasClean: event.wasClean,
          code: event.code,
          reason: event.reason
        }));

      return Observable.merge(message$, close$);
    });
```

This code makes a couple assumptions:

- That you want to handle `event.wasClean === true` errors. This example uses both closeObserver and catch, but you don't have to. It's not clear if you only care about unclean closes or all of them. It's also important to know that unclean CloseEvents are not the only errors WebSocketSubject can throw. Errors from `socket.onerror` are sent there as well as JS exceptions.
- that our subscription to `webSocket$` will complete() when the socket closes, which it does. If it didn't we'd want to `webSocket$.takeUntil(webSocketClose$).map(...)`

---

Separately I wanted to point out that rxjs's catch operator requires you to return an Observable, but your example returned a boolean. This would produce an error. If you only want to log the error instead of handling it, use the `do` operator.

```
// BAD
.catch((err) => { console.log(err);return true; })

// GOOD
.do({ error: (err) => console.log(err) })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! :)
I rechecked and my WS indeed was throwing `1006` instead of `1000` and that makes proper sense now. Thanks again for the tips on closeObserver.

The boolean in the catch was just a temp thing I was debugging at the time.

Comment: @jayphelps I'm not using `webSocketClose$`, but found an issue when trying to set `webSocket` using `mapSwitchTo`. `catchError` needs to be piped to `webSocket` directly and cannot be used after a `switchMapTo`.

Comment: So, just to be sure the ``closeObserver`` is actually a safe way to handle a ``isConnected`` state, right? It always emits - not matter if ``e.wasClean`` or not?

Comment: @YannicHamann yep https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c67c3e93a8b49818f17d0504728356a7628723d3/src/internal/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L334-L345